# Cannot pass typed Collection as method parameter

Tags: java

Here's a scenario where you can't pass a typed Collection as a method parameter:

```java
public static Collection<Category> allCategories(){
    return Arrays.asList(
            Category.firstCategory(),
            Category.secondCategory(),
            Category.thirdCategory()
    );
}
```

And a method

```java
public void setAcceptableValues(Collection<T> newValues) {
// ...
}
```

And this does not work:

`setAcceptableValues(allCategories());`

How do you pass a typed Collection as method parameter?

Comment: Where does `T` comes from? Ima kinda thinking that you need `public <T> void setAcceptableValues(Collection<T> newValues)` instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution for this is to do:

```java
public <V extends T> void setAcceptableValues(Collection<V> newValues) {
}
```

This way it's still safe to cast previously `Collection<T>` and now `Collection<V>`